# Legal usage of fonts distributed with Microsoft Windows (in `TeX Live` programs)

Tags: fonts, luatex, licensing

After I've read [OpenType and TrueType specification](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-font-license-restrictions-6be9f366-e722-4751-90a8-165e9c37e985) that [Microsoft website links to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq) (when I was looking about fonts licensing), I didn't fully understand that. So I'm asking a very specific question: can I use, distribute, print, publish, sell document or book that was written using `latex` or `lualatex` (distributed with `TeX Live`) and Microsoft fonts, specifically `Times New Roman`, `Arial` and `Courier New` (from [apt package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ttf-mscorefonts-installer))? Or any subset of listed action? Or I have to either use `Word`, buy the license that allows listed actions, or just get a free alternative?

P.S. `Okular` shows `embedded (subset)` and `CID TrueType` in document (that is using specified font) fonts properties.

Comment: legal questions are off topic. Not all microsoft fonts have the same licence, it depends which font it is. Older ones in "core fonts" including Times New Roman  (but not, for example, Cambria Math) have a licence allowing the font to be distributed to other platforms (eg linux, hence the apt package you link to). Others are not licenced to be used except on the windows box they were distributed with. Either way, mostly there is not a restriction on documents that have a subset font embdded but for commercial use you should to check the licence of each font, not trust any answer here

Comment: I don't think any of the licences restrict typesetting software, just in some cases restrict operating system. So if you can use Word, you can use luatex.

Comment: This is indeed off-topic, you can ask on [Open Source.SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) or [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) instead.